# Why is the connection between the Android emulator and a PC so slow?

Tags: usb, android-emulator, file-transfer

Host OS: Windows 7 x86

Android emulator target: 2.3.3

When I execute 'adb pull' or 'adb push' with emulator - transfer speed is about 70KB/s.
When I do this with real device it's normal USB speed. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Because the emulator is buggy and slow and should be avoided if possible when developing. I'm assuming its because of the general problem with emulators, it is trying to mimic hardware functions on a software level which is extremely inefficient.

Comment: I agree with you that it's slow because it emulates arm architecture on x86, but it's not so buggy.

Comment: Now I use emulator for testing custom images. Yesteday I rooted standart Android 2.3.3 image and installed Android Market on it. To do so I needed to build system.img from /system fs with mkfs.yaffs2 and then pulling system.img from emulator and this was very long, because image is ~90MB size. Also I do not understand where is bottleneck in transfer, I think it's more an implementation detail or restriction.